# Release notes for appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Are there some release notes for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` sometimes the changes are quite notable. I have searched through google and on android dev pages but no luck.

Comment: appcompat+release+note+google+first_link= http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find all the details about the Support Library package releases:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: beat me to the second, I was about to bring the same link https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#revisions